# Classes generated by custom T4 generator look messy

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4

After running the generator output files with code look really disordered. I know I will probably never look into those files but it is nice to see generated code nicely structured while developing a generator.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Change the template so that the code it outputs is formatted?  Aside from the fact that the class names are fully qualified rather than just the class name and a using statement at the top, I've never had an issue code from my templates.

Comment: +1 true is painful working with T4 because it is almost impossible to keep generated code properly idented

Comment: I always keep the generated code clean and formatted. I don't Think it is painful at all. My reasoning for doing is that you will debug the generated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> never look into those files

as long as the code works, who cares. rest easy friend, move on to more important things :)

but if you REALLY want to do this, I'd suggest adding a code-reformatting process to your continuous build system. see [How to force code style formatting as part of the build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352947/how-to-force-code-style-formatting-as-part-of-the-build) for an example

Comment: well I know but I'm currently working on this T4 generator and I have to "see" if the code is right :)

Comment: ah ok. If you don't want to change your T4 template to do proper formatting, you can do Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document as a quick and easy way to reformat code on demand

Comment: there's also this extension http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99 which will automatically format your file when you save it

Answer (score 1):

Change your t4 code to make the output code neater... or don't look.

Comment: you mean everything depends how I structure the code in the generator itself ?

Comment: I would say there is only one option. Change the t4 code. You will need to look and debug.